# How can I get these images to stop 'flickering' when they switch?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble with a jQuery image rotator. When the next/previous buttons are clicked twice quickly, the image flickers and you end up seeing both images. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="prev">
<img id="prevListing" class="prevListing" src="..." onmouseover="this.src='...'" onmouseout="this.src='...'">
</div>

<div class="faded">
<div id="fader">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
</div>
</div>

<div id="next">
<img id="nextListing" class="nextListing" src="..." onmouseover="this.src='...'" onmouseout="this.src='...'">
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.used {float:left; width:50%;}

.usedListingImage {width:65%;float:left; display:block; margin:-1% auto 0 auto; max-width:400px;}

#fader{display:block;  width:95%;}

.nextListing {width:5%;float:right; margin:6% 5% 5% 5%;padding-right:5%;}

.prevListing  {width:5%;float:left; margin:7% 5% 5% 5%; }
```

and the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery (function() {
    $('#fader img:not(:first)').hide();

    $('#fader img').each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        $('<img>').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).load(function() {
            img.css('margin-left', -'0');
        });
    });

    var pause = false;

    function fadeNext() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut().appendTo($('#fader'));
        $('#fader img').first().fadeIn();
    }

    function fadePrev() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut();
        $('#fader img').last().prependTo($('#fader')).fadeIn();
    }

    $('#fader, #next').click(function() {
        fadeNext();
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        fadePrev();
    });

    $('#fader, .button').hover(function() {
        pause = true;
    },function() {
        pause = false;
    });

    function doRotate() {
        if(!pause) {
            fadeNext();
        }    
    }

    var rotate = setInterval(doRotate, 5000);

});

</script>
```

Any ideas how I can stop the flickering when images switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently initiating the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` at the same time, causing a brief overlap. You may want to change `fadeIn` to a callback instead:

```
function fadeNext() {
    $('#fader img').first().fadeOut(400, function(){
            $('#fader img').first().fadeIn();
    }).appendTo($('#fader'));

}

function fadePrev() {
    $('#fader img').first().fadeOut(400, function(){
        $('#fader img').last().prependTo($('#fader')).fadeIn();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently have `float:left;` in you css. When you have `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` running at the same time both elements are visible and in the space and there isn't enough room so the other image drops down below the first image. You should use `position: absolute;` on them so that they can exist in the same space. Then I would just change the z-index to the image on the image fading in so it is on top and don't worry about fading the old image out, just `hide()` it after the other image is finished fading in.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, the images are showing up at the same time since the overflow is not being hidden in any way. An example of stacking them on top of each other can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/ocitok/1/edit) using

```
width:85%; position: relative; float: left;
```

on

```
#fader
```

and

```
position:absolute;
```

on

```
.usedListingImage
```